# What is chroot in proftpd

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I am using proftpd and on every login I get the following message:

```
Apr  4 08:26:23 
mydomain proftpd[4240]: 
mydomain.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]) - 
FTP session opened. 

Apr  4 08:26:23 
mydomain proftpd[4240]: 
mydomain.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]) - 
Preparing to chroot to directory 'path-to/domain'
```

Can anyone explaom to me what this means. Everything works fine however, the are no other messages except for these 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chroot` is an operating system call that restricts an application to be able to access only a subset of the filesystem -- in effect, that part of the filesystem becomes the root, which it can't see outside of.

This is done for security reasons, to create a "jail" which an FTP client can't see beyond.

Comment: So there is no problem with this message, I however previously not got them, only the last few days

Comment: @Saif - correct, it is normal and expected for any security-conscious FTP daemon to be using chroot. I can only speculate on why you wouldn't have seen this in the past -- security update impacting the logging code? log settings change? etc.